# Exporting a raster from Netlogo 6.0 using the GIS extension- patch variables vs global variables

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to use the GIS extension of NetLogo 6.0 to export a raster of the NetLogo patches with the value of a patch variable. I'm using the GIS  primitive `gis:patch-dataset`, since according to the GIS extension dictionary it is supposed to:

> "report a new raster whose cells correspond directly to NetLogo patches, and whose cell values consist of the values of the given patch variable."

However, this primitive does not seem to work if I use a patch variable as its parameter. It *does* work if I use a global variable, but of course this reports the single value of that global variable. Can anyone see what I'm missing? Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding how `gis:patch-dataset` works, but as far as I understand `gis:patch-dataset` should require a patch variable in order to report a raster.

**Code example below**. I run `setup` then I try to run `test-gis-output`, but get the error that I can't use `test-gis-output` in an observer context, since it is `turtle/patch` only. This makes sense to me from an error standpoint, global, turtle, and patch variables are separate. However, how can I report a raster of all patches without referencing a patch-only variable?

```
extensions [
  gis
]

globals [
  test_file
]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
    ask patches with [pxcor mod 2 = 0 ] [
    set pcolor red
  ]
end

to test-gis-output
  set test_file gis:patch-dataset pcolor
  gis:store-dataset test_file "test_export"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetLogo was telling me what I needed to know all along- only patches can use the `gis:patch-dataset primitive.` Using the following code worked to export an ASCII raster:

```
to test-gis-output
  ask patches [
    set test_file gis:patch-dataset pcolor
  ]
  gis:store-dataset test_file "test_export"
end
```